# Mailto on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get mailto working on page load below is the code i am trying to get working

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function mymessage() {
        window.open('mailto:address@example.com');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="mymessage()">
  </body>
</html>
```

it does ask to open a popup but is there any other i can get it working without the need of pop-ups allowed ?

Comment: use `window.location = 'mailto:address@example.com';`

Comment: Browser's won't let you. It is most likely to be considered spam.

Comment: Even if you could get this to work, it would only open the client's default email program. It wouldn't send anything.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect, it works on all browser as tested by me.
The problem might be the pop-up blocked by your browser as every modern browser does.

You can see "pop-up blocked" error on right hand side or URL bar.